# Shrink flex item to fit content

Tags: css, flexbox

Here's a sample:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a {
  background: lightGreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is some text.</a>
```

The `<a>` element stretches as long as the page width. How can we shrink it so it fits the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Align the flex items to the start side of the cross-axis. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

a {
  background: lightGreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is some text.</a>
<a href="#">This is some longer text.</a>
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `start`, `flex-start`, and `baseline` values?

Comment: Not in most cases. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items